# Property 'select' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am new in Angular and trying to make an ecommerce project so I want to filter my products based on what is in queryParams of the URL.

So lets say I have URL as

```
http://localhost:4200/?category=Fruits
```

so it should filter all the products of category as Fruits

Here is the code for that

html File

```html
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <ul class="list-group" <a *ngFor="let c of categories" class="list-group-item" routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" [queryParams]="{category:c.name}">
      {{c.name}}
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let p of products;let i=index" class="row-eq-height">
        <div class="col">
          <mdb-card style="width:17rem;" class="c1">
            <div class="view rgba-white-slight waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>
              <mdb-card-img [src]="p?.imageurl" alt="Card image cap" class="cardimg"> </mdb-card-img>
              <a>
                <div class="mask"></div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <mdb-card-body>
              <mdb-card-title>
                <h4>{{p?.title}}</h4>
              </mdb-card-title>
              <mdb-card-text>$ {{p?.price}}
              </mdb-card-text>
              <button mdbBtn type="button" color="primary" size="sm" mdbWavesEffect>Add to Cart</button>
            </mdb-card-body>
          </mdb-card>
        </div>

      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

.component.ts

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductsService } from '../services/products.service';
import { ItemsService } from '../services/items.service';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  products;
  categories;
  query;
  filteredproducts;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private prservice: ProductsService, private iservice: ItemsService, private activatedrouter: ActivatedRoute) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.iservice.getdata().subscribe(data => {
      this.products = data;
      console.log(this.products)
    });

    this.subscription = this.iservice.getitems().subscribe(categ => {
      this.categories = categ;
    });

    this.activatedrouter.queryParams.subscribe(p => {
      this.query = p['category'];
      console.log(this.query)

      this.filteredproducts = this.products.pipe(filter(p => p.select === this.query));
      console.log(this.filteredproducts)

    });
  }

  OnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

So here is the screenshot of my products that I get in my console 
https://ibb.co/FnKDvsk

And now I have applied filter function to the "select" to filter the products

The errors I am facing are

1. Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
2. Property 'select' does not exist on type '{}'.

Comment: I am not getting this line "this.filteredproducts=this.query?this.products.pipe()" why you are using  "this.query?"  in your code?

Comment: @SnehaPawar never mind it was just an extra step now i have edited it ! You can take a look again .

Comment: Error 1: just as the error states `this.products` is undefined so calling any member on it will yield that error.

Comment: I guess you are running this line `this.filteredproducts = this.products.pipe` before you get data. You can quick fix this by initializing the products variable like `products = []`; or put this line inside `this.subscription = this.iservice.getdata().subscribe(data`

Comment: Your HTML is invalid; probably not the cause of your errors, but something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why it's happening? Because `this.products` is undefined and you are applying `pipe` on undefined.

Solutions:
Initialized `products` in the beggning : `products = []`

Or

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.iservice.getdata().subscribe(data => {
    this.products = data;
    console.log(this.products)

    this.activatedrouter.queryParams.subscribe(p => {
      this.query = p['category'];
      console.log(this.query)
      this.filteredproducts = Object.create(this.products);
      this.filteredproducts = this.filteredproducts.filter(p => p.select === this.query);
      console.log(this.filteredproducts)

    });
  });

  this.subscription = this.iservice.getitems().subscribe(categ => {
    this.categories = categ;
  });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i edited the wrong answer. I applied a roll back immediately after I realized that.

Comment: @Igor Actually the edit was right. He does not need to add `pipe` and can apply filter method on the products array.

Comment: @Maihan one more issue i get the output in console only for the very first if i click on any category after then on clicking on any of the category i am not receivng anything in the console !

Comment: @rupak it's because of the reference you have between original and filtered arrays. Use deep copy `Object.create()`. See edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Error 1: just as the error states `this.products` is undefined so calling any member on it will yield that error. One way to fix this is to move the call to inside the callback for when `this.products` will be assigned a value. Example:

The other error is you are trying to apply `pipe/filter` to a returned array. This can only be applied to an observable, it is a part of the rxjs library. Just use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) directly on the returned array.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.iservice.getdata().subscribe(data => {
    this.products = data;
    console.log(this.products);
    this.activatedrouter.queryParams.subscribe(p => {
      this.query = p['category'];
      console.log(this.query)

      this.filteredproducts = this.products.filter(p => p.select === this.query);
      console.log(this.filteredproducts)
    });       
  });

  this.subscription = this.iservice.getitems().subscribe(categ => {
    this.categories = categ;
  });
}
```

---

Error 2: `Property 'select' does not exist on type '{}'.`

The returned product instances do not contain a `select` member. Or perhaps this is caused elsewhere in your code but this is the only place in the shared code where you included a call to a member `select`.

Comment: one more issue i get the output in console only for the very first if i click on any category after then on clicking on any of the category i am not receivng anyhting in the console !